# Avoid CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS in Django 4.1

Tags: django, docker, nginx, cors

I've a dockerized Django project which I access through NGINX. I just upgraded to Django 4.1 and now it seems that it's mandatory to define a CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS listing, I would like to know if there is a way to allow POST requests from any source.

I've tried installing https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers and setting CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS to TRUE but it didn't work :/

This are my settings right now:

```py
# ...

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True


# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...

    'django_extensions',
    'rest_framework',
    'adrf',

    'corsheaders',

    'django_object_actions',
    'crispy_forms',
    'widget_tweaks',

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

# ...
```

Also I tried setting CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['*'] as I have in ALLOWED_HOSTS but it doesn't work...

Thank you so much!

Comment: Did you also add `corsheaders` to `INSTALLED_APPS` and `corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware` before `django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware` ?

Comment: Yes, I just eddited the question with my settings.py content